# Get the position of a given item in an ArrayList

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of type Vertex. Vertex is my own class which contains only one data member of String type. It has a member function getName() which returns the name of the Vertex.
I want to get the position in the ArrayList, if a particular string is given. I've written the below code to do it. But it always returns -1, which is the initial value. What is the problem with my code?

```
    public int map(String vname)
    {
        int pos=-1;
        for(int i=0;i<nodes.size();i++)
        {
            if(nodes.get(i).getName()==vname)
            {
                pos=i;
                break;  
            }
        }
        return pos;
    }
```

In the above code, nodes is an ArrayList of type Vertex.

Comment: NOOOOO.. not agaaaaaain :_( Don't use `==` to compare strings in Java. Use `equals`.

Comment: Everytime a string is compared with `==` for equality in Java, a developer cries (@MarounMaroun case and point)

Comment: For reference types, please understand that there is a conceptual difference between identity and equality.  Using the '==' operator for reference types asks "is this reference type the very same one as the other."  To ask, "are the values of these objects equal (even if they are different objects)" you must use the .equals() method.

Comment: @MarounMaroun thank u, i got the correct value now

Comment: @AparnaShajiPeter See the String API, it should help you to better understand it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.String)

Comment: it looks like you are coming from C background

Comment: then it would have been strcmp ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [String#equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29): `nodes.get(i).getName().equals(vname)` instead. `==` in Java compares address of the 
string.

Answer (score 4):

In Java `==` is for object equality, `string1.equals(string2)` is for string equality

Comment: Good Guy MarounMaroun, doesn't post an answer, makes everyones answers better

Comment: I got enough reputation points from `==` vs `equals`, it's your time to shine now :D

Answer (score 4):

`==`  compares references not the content.

Use [String#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)  if case is important otherwise use [String#equalsIgnoreCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @Maroun Maroun Thanks for edit

Comment: @Maroun Maroun  you are doing good job man

Answer (score 2):

You `String` comparison is wrong...

```
if(nodes.get(i).getName()==vname)
```

Should be

```
if(nodes.get(i).getName().equals(vname))
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace it with

```
if(nodes.get(i).getName()==vname)
```

to

```
if(nodes.get(i).getName().equals(vname))
```

for comparing String with the case And for Comparing vname without case use

```
if(nodes.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(vname))
```